# How can I validate EU Social Security Number?

Tags: regex

Is there a regex for social security number (id) in EU?

Comment: Tell us how does an EU SSN look like.

Comment: What does the target number look like?

Comment: Unless it was introduced very recently, I don't believe there is such a thing as a unified SSN for the EU.  The closest may be the `Personal Identification Number` found on the optional/on-demand European Health Insurance Card.

Comment: Yes, at least give us the spec, Wikipedia article, anything. Most of us probably aren't citizen of EU member.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number

Seems like you need to implement a unique validation method for each country's SSN. Regex isn't enough, a fake SSN may look valid, but is not. There's a certain algorithm for generating the whole SSN for each country.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you from living in the UK, that there is no SSN - but there is the equivalent of a National Insurance Number.  From my experience, with the exception of my employer, NOBODY needed this number.  With the guidelines inside of the US regarding PII (Personally Identifiable Information), you should not be collecting even partial SSN's wherever possible.

It might be a good idea to look at other methods for data collection and user validation (or whatever your use case may be) before you request SSN, National Insurance Number or any other unique government-issued number.